# Symfony FileSystem deletes what it should not delete

Tags: php, symfony

I am having troubles with Symfony Filesystem class. I am trying to delete a folder via remove method.

This is my method.

```
public function createArchive($source, $destination) {
        $zipper = new Zipper();
        $zipper->make('backup/'.$this->getBackupName().'.zip')->add('backup/'.$this->getBackupName().'/');

        $fileSystem = new Filesystem();
        $fileSystem->remove('backup/'.$this->getBackupName());
    }
```

Zipper creates zip archive with folder i put in second argument. So for example i have a folder backup/2016_03_24_full it will create zip archive in backup/2016_03_24_full.zip.

Then i am trying to remove the backup/2016_03_24_full folder so only zip archives are there. But Filesystem remove method is deleting also my zip. It should delete only folder i put in argument, but something is going wrong..

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're passing a folder to the remove method, it first tries to delete the directory by calling `rmdir()`. This function expects the folder to be empty. Since your directory is not empty, a fallback comes into play which relies on PHP's FilesystemIterator.

My guess is that giving the name of the folder without the trailing slash (/) is picking the files from outside and inside the folder both and removing them.

You can see the concrete algorithm [here](https://github.com/symfony/filesystem/blob/master/Filesystem.php#L156).